# Order sub-tree navigation using ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ancestry

I'm following the rails cast [Tree Based Navigation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation-revised).

I want to order the sub-tree alphabetically.

In my PagesController I have

```
@page_for_nav = Admin::Page.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
```

which gets called by

```
<%= render 'layouts/sub_navigation', pages: @page_for_nav.root.descendants.arrange %>
```

which renders

```
<ul>
  <% pages.each do |page, children| %>
    <% if page.page_status == 'Public' %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to_unless_current page.name, "../#{page.permalink}" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/sub_navigation', pages: children if children.present? %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Doing this in my PagesController fails (no error given, it just doesn't order)

```
@page_for_nav = Admin::Page.order("name asc").find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
```

and doing this on the each which also fails (no error given, it just doesn't order)

```
<% pages.each.order("name asc") do |page, children| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `:order => :name` option to `arrange` method

```
<%= render 'layouts/sub_navigation', pages: @page_for_nav.root.descendants.arrange(:order => :name) %>
```

Read the doc: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#arrangement

Comment: Lovely! I must be blind as a bat!